# atan2 function behaves different in javascript and excellsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, javascript

I am trying the atan2 Math Function but i am getting wrong value in google excel sheet. but getting correct value in javascript atan2 function. How can i get that value in excelsheet ?

my value in excel is

```
atan2(8.6,2.7699)=0.3115
```

while in javascript is

```
atan2(8.6,2.7699)=1.259206466337312
```

I have checked javascript value here http://www.univie.ac.at/moe/rechner/rechner.html

can any one say why this happens ?

if i want this value in excel then what formula should i use ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Microsoft Excel the atan2 function takes the parameters in reverse order and Google Docs does the same thing for consistency. If you flip the parameters in javascript you get the same "wrong" value.

Answer (score 6):

The function signature for atan2 in Excel is [ATAN2(**x**_num, **y**_num)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/atan2-HP005208991.aspx) while in Javascript it's [Math.atan2(**y,x**)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2). Note the order of arguments.

They should both give your roughly the same answer if you provide the arguments in the appropriate order.

Answer (score 0):

Excel's `ATAN2` requires the `x`-coordinate followed by the `y` coordinate `ATAN2(x,y)` but JavaScript `ATAN2` has the arguments reversed : `ATAN2(y,x)`