# VBA haversine formula

Tags: excel, vba, formula, haversine

I am trying to implement Haversine formula into excel function. Its looks like this:

```
Public Function Haversine(Lat1 As Variant, Lon1 As Variant, Lat2 As Variant, Lon2 As Variant)
Dim R As Integer, dlon As Variant, dlat As Variant, Rad1 As Variant
Dim a As Variant, c As Variant, d As Variant, Rad2 As Variant

R = 6371
dlon = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Radians(Lon2 - Lon1)
dlat = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Radians(Lat2 - Lat1)
Rad1 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Radians(Lat1)
Rad2 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Radians(Lat2)
a = Sin(dlat / 2) * Sin(dlat / 2) + Cos(Rad1) * Cos(Rad2) * Sin(dlon / 2) * Sin(dlon / 2)
c = 2 * Excel.WorksheetFunction.Atan2(Sqr(a), Sqr(1 - a))
d = R * c
Haversine = d
End Function
```

But when im testing it I am getting wrong distance... I dont understand why. For coordinates used in this topic : [Function to calculate distance between two coordinates shows wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883601/function-to-calculate-distance-between-two-coordinates-shows-wrong)
I am getting 20013,44 as output. Anyone knows what is wrong here? Cant find my mistake...

Comment: Just a question: why did you choose "Variant" as a data type, and not "double"? Second, did you already try to make a simple Excel file for this, using Excel formulas? That would make it easier to understand what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Atan2 is defined back to front in Excel compared to JavaScript i.e. Atan2(x,y) rather than Atan2(y,x).

You need to reverse the order of the two arguments:-

```
c = 2 * Excel.WorksheetFunction.Atan2(Sqr(1 - a), Sqr(a))
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718023/atan2-function-behaves-different-in-javascript-and-excellsheet)

So

```
=haversine(59.3293371,13.4877472,59.3225525,13.4619422)
```

gives

```
1.65 km
```

which is the correct distance as the crow flies.

Comment: Wow, This was brilliant. Takes an experienced person to know the subtlety.

Answer (score 0):

Great tool! Just underscoring that the result will be in **kilometers**, so if you want **miles** multiply the result by 0.62137.